# Importing excel data to dataGridView

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I've written the code below that allows the data in Excel to transfer to the dataGridView box. I have one text box that allows the user to input which sheet number they want to extract the data from. Because my Excel is in Turkish, the sheet numbers are labeled Sayfa1, Sayfa2 and so on.

However I keep on getting this error message: "external table is not in the expected format".

Can anyone tell me what the problem might be? I am using windows application form in C#.

```
private void button_kaydet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      string PathConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +                  "C:\\Users\\casperpc\\Desktop\\hey.xlsx" + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\";";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(PathConn);
      OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * [" + txtbx_sheetName.Text + "$]", conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      myDataAdapter.Fill(dt);

      dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add "from" after "select *" in order to make the query work. Was that causing your problem? It threw an "Invalid Query" exception, not a data in unexpected type exception, when I ran it before inserting "from", but with the "from" operator, it functions exactly as I expected.

Is there anything unusual about the format of your .xlsx file?